# Intsallation of ffmpeg-php on Amazon Ec2 Linux AMI

Tags: php, linux, amazon-ec2, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I am about two days into attempting to install FFMPEG-php with dependencies on an AWS EC2 instance running the Amazon Linux AMI. I've installed FFMPEG, and have read reportedly successful instructions on installing on Red Hat/Fedora. I have followed a number of tutorials and forum articles to do so, but have had no luck yet. As far as I can tell, the main problems are as followed:

I have installed all the dependency for ffmpeg-php. I run the following command successfully.

$wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ffmpeg-php/ffmpeg-php/0.6.0/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0.tbz2
$tar xvfj ffmpeg-php-0.6.0.tbz2
$phpize

But when I run the following command it throw the error like below:

$sudo ./configure

configure: error: ffmpeg shared libraries not found. Make sure ffmpeg is compiled as shared libraries using the --enable-shared option}

I have used enable shared option with shared enable option but it throw the same error.

On to my question: Has anyone successfully installed FFMPEG-php on Amazon Linux? Is there a fundamental incompatibility? If anyone could share specific instructions on installing ffmpeg-php on amazon linux I would be greatly appreciative. Any other insights/experiences would also be appreciated.